# GCP : Identify correct instance(N1standard 8, N1Highmem etc.) using catlog API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

We are currently working on **GCP pricing module** and for that we are using [GCP catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api) to get the pricing for various GCP services.

While analyzing the response of catalog api for `Compute Engine`, we observed that there is no any exact parameter in the sku object with which we could identify the machine type(N1Standard 4, NIHighmem 16 etc.) except description.

Other than parsing the description, is there any workaround to directly get the sku object with particular number of cores?

Is there any workaround to directly get the sku object for particular instance name?

for example : `N1Standard 16` 
Following  is sample sku object for N1Highcpu with 8 cores where the number of cores are only mentioned in description.:

```
{
      "name": "services/<<id>>/skus/C216-207D-0521",
      "skuId": "C216-207D-0521",
      "description": "Highcpu Intel N1 8 VCPU running in Netherlands",
      "category": {
        "serviceDisplayName": "Compute Engine",
        "resourceFamily": "Compute",
        "resourceGroup": "N1Highcpu",
        "usageType": "OnDemand"
      },
      "serviceRegions": [
        "europe-west4"
      ],
      "pricingInfo": [
        {
          "summary": "",
          "pricingExpression": {
            "usageUnit": "h",
            "usageUnitDescription": "hour",
            "baseUnit": "s",
            "baseUnitDescription": "second",
            "baseUnitConversionFactor": 3600,
            "displayQuantity": 1,
            "tieredRates": [
              {
                "startUsageAmount": 0,
                "unitPrice": {
                  "currencyCode": "USD",
                  "units": "0",
                  "nanos": 312400000
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "currencyConversionRate": 1,
          "effectiveTime": "2018-05-17T08:22:54.236Z"
        }
      ],
      "serviceProviderName": "Google"
    }
```

Comment: Did you use the link mentioned by Marc  https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json.

Comment: I have referred ans by Diogo. I have used pricelist.json before. but you can see in json `"comment": "This JSON data is obsolete. Please use https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api instead.",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features you need have not been implemented yet on the Cloud Billing Catalog API.

As for the moment the only workaround would be parsing the output to get the SKU for the Compute Engine instances. So, please follow up the feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111070261).

Comment: 2020 and there's still no way to get pricing information for a compute engine machine type. That's crazy. The only thing is `https://console.cloud.google.com/m/price_list?folder&organizationId`

Comment: 2022 and it looks like only way is the link mentioned above https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json